# How to make a long word get displayed as a shorter word in an emacs buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was reading the source of `rainbow-delimiters.el` and then I was trying to replace the word `rainbow-delimiters` with `RD` using the code I got from somewhere that replaces the word `lambda` with its greek letter.

This is the code I came up with and it doesn't do what I want.

```
(defun my-simplify-prefix (prefix)
  ;; (interactive "sPrefix: ")
  (interactive (list "rainbow-delimiters"))
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil `((,(rx-to-string `(group ,prefix))
          (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                    "RD")
                    nil)))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

What it does instead is it replaces `rainbow-delimiters` with one letter which is a combination of R and D.

Comment: This seems to be the documented behavior of `compose-region`. Why don't you just lose it and use the string `"RD"` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun my-simplify-prefix (prefix)
  (interactive "sPrefix: ")
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil `((,(rx-to-string `(group ,prefix))
           (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                        'display "RD")
                     nil)))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```